# Rebinding the DataContext of a Window in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, data-binding, .net-4.0

I have a Window in WPF for which i have defined a dataContext. I have a save button an on clicking the save button i am adding the updated datacontext to a collection and define a new instance of the datacontext object for the current window. Now how do i update the window with the new DataContext.

I tried this

```
  this.DataContext=insClassA;//Initially it is set

  //Later on some event i'm updating the NewAttributeProperty
  insClassA.NewAttribute = new NewAttribute();
```

but the UIFields still hold the previous instance's values/

Thanks.

Comment: Is there some specific reason you are creating a new instance of the DataContext?

Comment: Can you post some code? How do you set the DataContext in the first place?

Comment: To be specific i have a usercontrol which capture some information and add it to the main window's datacontext. So on clicking add i want to update the information in mainwindow's datacontext and enable the user to enter a new information in the usercontrol.(The user control comes as a pop-up)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should take place automatically. If you set a new instance of your object to the DataContext-property of you window, all bound items should refresh automatically.

**UPDATE:**

Based on your edit, I assume that your object does not implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) and ist not a DependencyObject or the failing property is not a DependencyProperty. The problem seems to me not about the DataContext.

Your object must inform the environment, that the property has been changed. Normaly, BOs do this with the PropertyChanged-event. Search for WPF DataBinding and INotifyPropertyChanged and you will find a lot of information to this topic.